# In a Spring 3 controller, how can I check the permissions of the logged-in user and do certain actions conditionally?

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, permissions, spring-security

In Spring 3, is there a method that accepts a comma-separated list of permissions and returns a Boolean of whether the logged in user has any of those permissions?  I envision doing something like:

```
if(loggedInUserHasAnyOfThesePermissions("PERMISSION_READ,PERMISSION_EDIT")){
    //do stuff
}
```

Currently, since don't know of any such built-in method, I'm doing this:

```
Set<String> permissions = new HashSet();
for (GrantedAuthority auth : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()) {
    permissions.add(auth.getAuthority());
}

if (permissions.contains("PERMISSION_READ") || permissions.contains("PERMISSION_EDIT")) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I've searched for hours and haven't found a more concise and elegant way of doing this, but one must exist.  Thanks for your help!

P.S. I'm already familiar with how to handle permissions in JSP like this: ( [how to conditionally show jsp content to logged in users with Spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638170/how-to-conditionally-show-jsp-content-to-logged-in-users-with-spring-security) )  But what I need now is a way to check within the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding my own class: MyUserDetails class has various methods including one that iterates over roles and permissions to see all the permissions that a user has, such as:

```
for (Permission permission : role.getPermissions()) {
          permissions.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(permission.getName()));
        }
```

It's pretty ugly, but I don't have a better way yet.

I use it by doing something like:

```
MyUser loggedInUser = myUserDAO.getByUsername(principal.getName());
MyUserDetails loggedInUserUD = new MyUserDetails(loggedInUser);
if (loggedInUserUD.hasAnyPermission("perm1, perm2")){
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpServletRequest` has a method `isUserInRole`, which may be useful. Example:

```
public String someControllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
   boolean read = request.isUserInRole("PERMISSION_READ");
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Spring 3, is there a method that accepts a comma-separated list of permissions and returns a Boolean of whether the logged in user has any of those permissions?

No there is not.

I ended up defining and implementing my own convenience API to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html) and than use the [Pre and Post Annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-pre-post-annotations) which operates on a method level.

The actual logic behind the pre a post annotations is probably accessible so you can probably accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> In Spring 3, is there a method that accepts a comma-separated list of permissions and returns a Boolean of whether the logged in user has any of those permissions?

Are you talking about [ExpressionUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/ExpressionUtils.html) that can evaluate expressions such as `hasAnyRole([role1,role2])`?

Comment: maybe, but I don't know what you're saying/proposing. How can I do what I'm talking about? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan I guess in other forums too a question was asked if ExpressionUtils can be used to do the same elegantly. It has the evaluateAsBoolean method that takes expression and returns the boolean. It is used within Spring classes but I wonder if we can use a similar approach within application classes.