# Best approach to secure (using roles and permissions) web application?

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security, security, cas

Thinking to use Spring security but is there better than that? Also, thinking to use CAS (Central Authentication Service) to integrate with Spring security for Single Sign On? Any suggestions? It might be different question but any idea how to use spring taglib in GWT to hide certain things based on user role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thinking to use Spring security but is there better than that?`
Maybe

`Also, thinking to use CAS (Central Authentication Service) to integrate with Spring security for Single Sign On? Any suggestions?`

Spring Security integrates seamlessly with CAS, you just need to do namespace based configuration and add beans when required on the client side.

[See Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html)

`It might be different question but any idea how to use spring taglib in GWT to hide certain things based on user role?`

Yes, you can do that using the security taglib like provided you include your GWT widgets into JSPs:

Here is a tutorial on how to do that but haven't tested it.

[custom-integration-of-gwt-widgets-into-jsps](http://aarendar.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-integration-of-gwt-widgets-into-jsps/)

and [the-role-of-jsps-in-a-gwt-world/](http://supplychaintechnology.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/the-role-of-jsps-in-a-gwt-world/)

See also:

- http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-gwt-spring-webapp-gwt.html
- [how to conditionally show jsp content to logged in users with Spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638170/how-to-conditionally-show-jsp-content-to-logged-in-users-with-spring-security)

Comment: I think only tricky bit is that you have to generate certificates to communicate between Spring and CAS Server. About spring taglib cannot see any use of that in the page specified above.

Comment: Check the stackoverflow question I have linked.

Comment: Checked many pros and cons of both. I think spring security is winner.

Comment: JSP tags do not work in GWT at all. GWT code compiled in JS that will be later executed in browser directly (client side technology). JSP tags are executed on server side (server side technology).

Comment: @MaksymDemidas, thats true..you have to do custom integration of GWT in your JSPs. I have updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend also the great (but maybe easier) security library from Apache: Shiro.

Here is the documentation to integrate with CAS: http://shiro.apache.org/cas.html.

Comment: Why Apache Shiro is it better than spring security?